# Most apposite word in the following sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

My Manager congratulated me **for/over/at/on** my winning first prize in the Elocution competition.

Comment: *on*; and I would remove *my*

Comment: @Em1 *for* would be OK too.

Comment: *for* or *on* are both ok, but *my* makes the sentence sound awkward to my ears.

Comment: *Most appropriate* is over a hundred times more common than *most apposite*: [COCA search results](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=34950637)

Answer (score 2):

The consensus from the comments is:

1. *On* is the proper preposition here, *BUT*
2. *congratulated me on **my** winning* is not colloquial English; most people would say simply *congratulated me on winning*.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most colloquial : "My Manager congratulated me **for winning** first prize in the Elocution competition."

This construct, "My Manager congratulated me **on winning** first prize in the Elocution competition." potentially means something akin to "My Manager congratulated when I won first prize in the Elocution competition.", i.e. it says something about the timing of when the congratulation was given.

The use of 'my' in of "me ... my winning" is redundant.  Why would your manager congratulate you for someone else's win?